# Initial Value Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this problem that I don't know how to approach. I have tried it a lot of different ways, but it doesn't seem like any of them are the way my teacher wants me to do it. 
$$\frac{\mbox{d}N}{\mbox{d}t} = 5N(3 - N)\ ,\ \ \ \ \ \ N(0) = 1$$
How does $N(t)$ behave as 't' approaches +infinity?

Comment: What ways have you tried?

Comment: I have learned separation, and for this equation that would leave me with dN/(5N(3-N))=dt, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the general solution is this, easily determined by separation of variables and direct integration and some elementary algebra afterwards.
(if you are interested in the steps, write me a comment and i'll add them)
$$\mbox{N}(t)=\frac{3e^{15t}}{e^{15t}+c_1}, \mbox{with } c\in \mathbb{R}$$
forcing the initial condition:
$$\mbox{N}(0)=\frac{3}{1+c_1}=1\in \mathbb{R}$$
solving for $c_1$ gives: $c_1=2$ so:
the particular solution is:
$$\mbox{N}(t)=\frac{3e^{15t}}{e^{15t}+2}$$
now let's find the limit:
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\mbox{N}(t)=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{3e^{15t}}{e^{15t}+2}=3$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended up being able to get it. I had to go back and look up what arctanh was in terms of ln. Then it was easy.

Comment: Alright! but why did you use arctanh? a simple partial fraction decomposition was sufficient to solve the integral ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 straionary points $0$ and $3$. One of them is  stable (asymptotically), one of them is not stable. Stability is easy to understand checking derivative around these point. So $0$ is obiously unstable since the derivative is positive when $N=\epsilon>0$  and negative when $N<0$. So the solution gets out from $0$-neighborhood. $3$ is the stable  stationary point by the similar reasoning. So you solution since it does not start from zero will asymptotically converge to $3$.

You actually don't have to solve the equation.